# How to load the images in views using ajax?

Tags: views, blocks, ajax, media, performance

There is a website with rich content (high resolution images).

I wish to load that view block contents (3 view blocks), but not the image, during the page load. Image should load in AJAX after the page load, without any external DOM element trigger. How can I achieve that?

#### Note

The whole point is increasing the performance without giving up on the functionality.

Comment: Sounds like something you will need to write custom code for. The https://drupal.org/project/jquery_ajax_load module might also be worth a look. Also, what does "40nos" mean in your question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [Image Lazy loader module](https://drupal.org/project/lazyloader)

> This is a small helper module which will automatically lazyload all
>   images for sites with multiple images, which will make the site load
>   faster.
>
> All images will only load when it's visible to the browser window.

Comment: will this help in front page load performance

Comment: @Bala yes and no, depends. If all images are visible from the beginning, it will only slow down loading, as it makes each single image load slower due to AJAX overhead. On the other hand if some images are not on the first screen, they will be skipped at first, so if their size will justify the overhead on the images that are, then you'll get apparent loading faster. If server and user agent supports HTTP pipelining, then by not using this module you can save a lot of time on connection negotiation. If files are small, connection negotiation can be more significant than data size. And so on...

Comment: @Mołot thanks sadly I need it for D6, any idea ?

Comment: @Bala Nope, except the one: start preparing to upgrade, as D6 support is going to end, and upgrading your site may require similar workload as backporting module, but will give you a lot more.

Comment: @Bala, https://drupal.org/project/lazy_image_loader appears to have a D6 version available. If that doesn't work for you, let me know, I plugged http://luis-almeida.github.io/unveil/ into a D6 theme here with a thattheme_image() to take care of its use that works pretty well.  But yes, alas, poor Yorick!  D6 is going away :(

Comment: @Jimajamma thanks I already installed lazy_image_loader and works well, but only concern with this module is not suitable for gallery formatter( https://drupal.org/project/galleryformatter ). it loads only the visible part. Do you have any idea ?

Comment: Ah...so you want ajax to load the full size image only when it needs to be displayed in the main larger area of the gallery, but just thumbnail sizes in the slider below?